# Add height of each div to parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container that needs to grow depending on the height of the elements inside of it.

here is my javascript

```
        function t($element) {

        var e = 0;

        $current = $('.w-slide.current');

        if ($element == null)
            $future = $current;
        else {
            if ($element.parent().hasClass('w-slider-arrow-right'))
                $future = $current.next()
            else
                $future = $current.prev()

        }

        $current.removeClass('current');
        $future.addClass('current');

        $('.section-wrapper').css('height', $future.height() + 'px');

    }

    jQuery('.w-slider-arrow-right .slide-arrow, .w-slider-arrow-left .slide-arrow').click(function() {
        t($(this));
    });

    $(window).ready(function() {
        $('.slide-mask .w-slide:nth-child(1)').addClass('current');
        t(null);
    });
```

When you click the slider-arrow-right it goes to the next slide and gets the height of all the elements in that container and the div grows or shrinks depending on how many elements and their height. When you click the slider-arrow-left it goes to the previous container and does the same as the left arrow.

Any help greatly appreciated. Ask for more context.

Cheers

Comment: Please post relevant HTML as well.

Comment: What is the specific problem or question? Provide a [mcve] also

Comment: hello sorry for the late reply.
you can find the LP here
http://test.aamplify.co/test.aamplify.co/sydney/eugene-rayner/